# JasperReports - JSON Data Report Shows Null Values when run in Java

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I am testing JasperReports with JSON data and running into a problem where null values are being displayed when generated from within a Java application. Here is what I have done so far:

In Studio, I created a report that uses the JSON File data provider using a file containing the following JSON:

```json
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "fullname":"John Stark",
            "employeeid":"29388282773",
            "phone":"415-293-2928"
        },
        {
            "fullname":"Mike Goodmann",
            "employeeid":"2938828282",
            "phone":"415-293-2726"
        },
        {
            "fullname":"David Simpson",
            "employeeid":"2938822837",
            "phone":"415-293-9826"
        },
        {
            "fullname":"Chris Humpty",
            "employeeid":"2938275452",
            "phone":"415-293-1122"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the resulting jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 7.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.4.3  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testreport" pageWidth="792" pageHeight="612" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="752" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" >
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="testdata"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[employees]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="fullname" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="fullname"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[fullname]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="employeeid" class="java.lang.Long">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="employeeid"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[employeeid]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="phone" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="phone"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[phone]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="240" y="24" width="280" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[Employee List]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="65" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="30" y="30" width="180" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[Full Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="240" y="30" width="160" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[Employee Id]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="430" y="30" width="180" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[Phone Number]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="299" y="0" width="100" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[employeeid]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="468" y="0" width="100" height="30" />
                <text><![CDATA[phone]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="24" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="180" height="20" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{fullname}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="241" y="0" width="159" height="20" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{employeeid}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="430" y="0" width="180" height="20" />
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{phone}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Then wrote a simple console app to generate the report in PDF but I get one row with NULL values. You will notice that I embedded the JSON into the class to simplify the test code until I get it to run correctly, and that I am indeed passing the JSON data into the "JasperFillManager.fillReport()" call.
Here is my Java code:

```java
public class ReportTester {
    String jsonData = "{\n" +
            "    \"employees\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"fullname\":\"John Stark\",\n" +
            "            \"employeeid\":\"29388282773\",\n" +
            "            \"phone\":\"415-293-2928\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"fullname\":\"Mike Goodmann\",\n" +
            "            \"employeeid\":\"2938828282\",\n" +
            "            \"phone\":\"415-293-2726\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"fullname\":\"David Simpson\",\n" +
            "            \"employeeid\":\"2938822837\",\n" +
            "            \"phone\":\"415-293-9826\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"fullname\":\"Chris Humpty\",\n" +
            "            \"employeeid\":\"2938275452\",\n" +
            "            \"phone\":\"415-293-1122\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";
    String reportFile = "/testreport.jrxml";
    String outputPdf = "testreport.pdf";
    JasperReport jasperReport;

    public void printme() {
        try {
            InputStream employeeReportStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportFile);
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(employeeReportStream);

            ByteArrayInputStream jsonDataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes());
            JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(jsonDataStream);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<String, Object>(), ds);

            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputPdf));
            SimplePdfReportConfiguration reportConfig = new SimplePdfReportConfiguration();
            reportConfig.setSizePageToContent(true);
            reportConfig.setForceLineBreakPolicy(false);
            exporter.setConfiguration(reportConfig);

            exporter.exportReport();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help point out what is wrong with this and why the report does not generate with data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What is wrong

You did not select data right. It means that *JR* engine prepared wrong input data for the report.

#### How to fix

All you need is to pass expression to the *JsonDataSource* instance for selecting right data.

Example:

```
JasperReport jasperReport;
try {
    try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportTemplate)) {
        jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
    }

    File outputFile = new File(outputFileName);
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    ByteArrayInputStream jsonDataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes());
    JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(jsonDataStream, "employees");
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, Maps.newHashMap(), ds);

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         OutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
        JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

        exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(byteArrayOutputStream));
        exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        exporter.exportReport();
        byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
    }
} catch (IOException | JRException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to build report", e);
}
```

All magic is here:

```
JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(jsonDataStream, "employees");
```

With help of expression `employees` we are selecting all nodes. You are doing the same at template or at data adapter at *JSS*.

We can view the source code of *JsonDataSource* class. We need *moveFirst* method.

```
@Override
public void moveFirst() throws JRException {
    if (jsonTree == null || jsonTree.isMissingNode()) {
        throw 
            new JRException(
                EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_NO_DATA,
                (Object[])null);
    }

    currentJsonNode = null;
    JsonNode result = getJsonData(jsonTree, selectExpression);
    if (result != null && result.isObject()) {
        final List<JsonNode> list = new ArrayList<JsonNode>();
        list.add(result);
        jsonNodesIterator = new Iterator<JsonNode>() {
            private int count = -1;
            @Override
            public void remove() {
                list.remove(count);
            }

            @Override
            public JsonNode next() {
                count ++;
                return list.get(count);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return count < list.size()-1;
            }
        };
    } else if (result != null && result.isArray()) {
        jsonNodesIterator = result.elements();
    }
}
```

In case selecting data with `employees` expression we have list of "employee" entities having *fullname, employeeid and phone* attributes.

With help of debugging tool we can view the data at this line of code:
`JsonNode result = getJsonData(jsonTree, selectExpression);`

[image: The data of JsonNode result]

In case using your code: `ByteArrayInputStream jsonDataStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonData.getBytes());` the data will be:

[image: The JsonNode result without using exression]

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for the great answer! Documentation is lacking and your answer solved my issue.

Comment: Alex, if I now want to expand my testing to a remote REST endpoint, do you know how to make this work? i.e. Studio allows me to create a JSON report that references a RESTful endpoint that returns the same JSON in my example, but how do I run that from a Java console app?